# Add barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper for Laravel to PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I add the `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` plugin into PhpStorm 2017.3.4 for Laravel 5.6. It seems that it does not work properly.

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

> Method 'middleware' not found in Route

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

> This one is ok

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

> Method 'channel' not found in Broadcast

**App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

> Multiple definitions exist for class Validator

**config/app.php**

```
'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,

],
```

> Multiple definitions exist for class App.Multiple definitions exist for class Artisan. All lines show these info.

What should I do? I just begin to learn to use Laravel.

Comment: 1) https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues -- yeah... 2) *"Multiple definitions exist for class Validator"* - disable appropriate inspection in PhpStorm -- no other workaround

Comment: I'd recommend disabling the "method not found" warnings as they are quite frequent. You'll quickly learn which methods exist within Laravel and when you do get it wrong, Laravel has a nice Exception page to help you realise what you did wrong.
You can disable the method not found warnings by going to Settings > Editor > Inspections > PHP > Undefined > Undefined method.

Comment: did you ran artisan commands?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following artisan commands:

- `php artisan ide-helper:generate`
- `php artisan ide-helper:models`
- `php artisan ide-helper:meta`

In fact I recommend to include it in the `post-update-cmd` part of your composer.json file so it runs these commands automatically everytime your do `composer update`

```
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:generate --tenant=tda",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:meta --tenant=tda",
      "@php artisan horizon:publish --ansi --tenant=tda",
    ]
```